# How to set assembly binding probing path for a C++/CLI DLL?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, app-config

I've written a C++/CLI DLL, using VS2012. My C++/CLI DLL wraps a third party native DLL. In turn, I think the third party native DLL then uses a bunch of other DLLs provided by the same third party package. There's a redistribute directory that contains a bunch of DLLs and things that this native DLL package uses.

Anyway, so when I add that redistribute directory on the system PATH, in Windows, I can load up my C++/CLI DLL in a separate C# GUI application.

When distributing this application though, I don't want to have to require the user to modify their PATH. Taking that redistribute directory out of PATH causes my C++/CLI DLL to fail to load, with a FileNotFound error. I'm pretty sure it's finding my DLL, because it's in the same directory, but I think it's failing to find the DLLs that mine depends on. I can't adjust PATH during run-time, in my GUI application, because it fails before main is called, while loading my CLI DLL.

I tried adding `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><probing privatePath="lib"/></assemblyBinding>` to the app.config, and putting all DLLs into a sibling lib directory, but that doesn't seem to fix it. I think it doesn't fix it because that just tells the C# GUI app where to find my CLI DLL, but doesn't tell the CLI DLL where to find it's deps, right?

Any ideas how I can fix this?